# RTK Query createApi results in: "Property '....' does not exist on type 'Api<BaseQueryFn>"

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

The following code uses RTK query to create a Redux Hook:

```
export const specialtiesApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'specialtiesApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://someplace.com/' }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getSpecialties: builder.query({
            query: (name) => `specialties`,
        }),
    }),
});

export const { useGetSpecialtiesQuery } = specialtiesApi;
```

The last line of code throws a Typescript compile-time error:

```
Property 'useGetSpecialtiesQuery' does not exist on type 'Api<BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta>, { getSpecialties: QueryDefinition<...>; }, "specialtiesApi", never, unique symbol>'
```

My code is adapted from https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage-with-typescript using Typescript 4.3.5.

I can't see what's wrong with it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Make sure you import the `createApi` and `fetchBaseQuery` functions from `@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react` module rather than `@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query`.

It should be:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
```

NOT:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query';
```

---

**UPDATE**

Also, see official documentation [API Slices: React Hooks](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks)

> However, RTK Query also provides the ability to auto-generate React hooks for each of your endpoints. Since this specifically depends on React itself, RTK Query provides an alternate entry point that exposes a customized version of createApi that includes that functionality:

```js
import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
```

> If you have used the React-specific version of createApi, the generated Api slice structure will also contain a set of React hooks.

Package versions:

```json
"typescript": "^4.3.5",
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1"
```

Comment: Fixed my issue, was staring at docs for a hot minute like, "This should just work, but it isn't..."

Comment: The magic of auto import somethimes gets it wrong. Daysaver!

Comment: If you are using the proper import path but still getting this type error,  install `typescript` to your project to get the warning to go away. I found I didn't have `typescript` in my dev dependencies yet.

Comment: In my case I had to update the typescript dependency to the latest version to resolve this issue.

Comment: Wow this is such a subtle issue that's caused by auto-importing which works great 9 out of 10 times, this resolved my issue!

Answer (score 3):

Also don't forget to add `use` and `Query` to your exported hook's name.

For example:

name of your endpoint: `getPhotoList`

name of the hook to be exported: `useGetPhotoListQuery`

Comment: This was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to wrap the export with **useMutation** and that's what was causing issue for me.  
<strike>*classic virgin nuub mistake</strike>

from

```
export const { signInUser } = authApi;
```

to

```
export const { useSignInUserMutation } = authApi;
```